# Sass: modifying all ID elements which name follows a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, sass

I am modifying a Wordpress template that creates new widgets with the form #id-name .panel-grid-cell 
as you can see here:

```
#pg-w58b983b2259ee-0 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58b983b2259ee-1 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58b983b2259ee-2 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58b983b2259ee-3 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58bd4d4e56422-0 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58bd4d4e56422-1 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58bd5656edd58-0 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd5656edd58-1 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd5656edd58-2 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd5656edd58-3 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd5656edd58-4 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd5656edd58-5 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58b9733479d6f-0 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58b9733479d6f-1 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58b9733479d6f-2 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58b9733479d6f-3 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-486-0 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-486-1 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58bd39810eb65-0 .panel-grid-cell,
#pg-w58bd3cc5d740c-0 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd3cc5d740c-1 .panel-grid-cell, 
#pg-w58bd3cc5d740c-2 .panel-grid-cell
{
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

The problem is that those names are created dynamically with JavaScript/JQuery.
It means the next time the user creates a new widget it will have a randomly created name with the same format

The question is:

**How could I set padding left and right to zero (0) in all the ID elements that their name follows the pattern: #id-name .panel-grid-cell using SASS?**

Something like:

```
$my-variable .panel-grid-cell
{
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
div[id^="pg-"]  .panel-grid-cell {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Don’t think that will work. The existing rules use important already - but they have a higher specificity, because they are using the id selector. I think you might need to increase specificity of your rule for this to work (for example by adding a leading id selector for a common parent element or sth. like that.)

Comment: @CBroe The existing rules are hardcoded right now and OP wants to get rid of them (as far as I understood) and any hardcoded selectors, so there will be no higher specificity.

Comment: Yep, it work!

However, the problem is that there are much more elements with the same name-pattern (I did not build this template). I will have to use another solution, but the solution is valid. therefore I mark it as accepted

Comment: @aquaman: I understood the question as if the CSS code as shown was dynamically generated by some sort of plugin and could not be changed/removed …

Comment: Yes, the CSS is generated via JavaScript, that's why I can not hardcode it, because the names are ramdomly created using always the same pattern. However, there are much more elements like that, not just the widgets, but also posts and pages